# How to create a lowscore tracker?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have a code that displays a game where the lowest score is the aim. In my code, the game can replay as many times as I want and is supposed to display the lowest score from all of the game plays. The changing variable is currentScore. It changes once the game is complete.

The current score can be between 0 and 80.

Here is what I've come up with that is always returning a "NEW LOW SCORE" when it shouldn't always be.

```
int lowestScore = 0;

if (currentScore < lowestScore) {
    
    lowestScore = currentScore;
    
    System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore + "  NEW LOW SCORE!");
    System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);
    
}
else {
    System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore);
    System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);
}
```

The output is supposed to show the lowest score value, regardless if it is a new lowest score or not. If it is a new lowest score, it is supposed to show "NEW LOW SCORE" and if not, just the current score and the previous lowest score.

I understand that this if statement doesn't work but I am truly stuck. Any ideas?

Here is a test case of my issue.

game runs and score is 45
outprint:
Score = 45 NEW LOW SCORE!
Lowest Score = 45

same sequence and game runs again, score is 78
outprint:
Score = 78 NEW LOW SCORE!
Lowest Score = 78

This is incorrect because in this case, this is what the output should look like:

game runs and score is 45
outprint:
Score = 45 NEW LOW SCORE!
Lowest Score = 45

same sequence and game runs again, score is 78
outprint:
Score = 78
Lowest Score = 45

Comment: What do you mean "doesn"t work" ?

Comment: if the initial value lowestScore is equal to 100, the current score is always going to be less than 100. Therefore the code will always assign the current score as the lowest score, even if it is not.

Comment: And how is that a problem ? A lower score is a better score as you said ?

Comment: It is a problem when i start a new game, and that score is higher then the score before, and the code still says "NEW LOW SCORE"

Comment: make lowest as zero.

Comment: By making zero, now the code will never go through the if statement, the code will always be "else"

Comment: Please [edit] your post and explain what sequence of score creates the problem. Because I don't see any problem

Comment: I tried all the answers given, and there is still an issue. These do not work. I appreciate your help in this, and will consider just posting the entire code because maybe the score loop should be added somewhere else to prevent this.

Comment: The provided code does not indicate the scope of `lowestScore`.  This variable is state for the execution of the program so it will need to be an instance or static variable (depending on how this is implemented).  The fact that you have provided no access modifier for it makes me think you have implemented this as a local variable that you may be initializing every time you execute this code.  That is not going to represent a running best score.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the lowest score in a variable you don´t override.

If you are using a database this is the place to store it.
If you are doing an in memory system you should use a place where the value is not constantly overriden.

It is not recommended, but in this case, it is possible to use a static variable, so it will be settled on the start up and then won´t override it again each call.

```
static int lowestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

I suggest you to set the first value to Integer.MAX_VALUE so it won´t need to change in case your maximum changes from 80 to 120 for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
int lowestScore = 0;

if(lowestScore == 0){
lowestScore=currentScore;
}
        if (lowestScore > currentScore) {

            lowestScore = currentScore;

            System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore + "  NEW LOW SCORE!");
            System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore);
            System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);
        }
```

as its a loop of games, when ever the user scores the least that will be stored in lowestScore.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an initial value that reflect the genesis lowest score: the maximum possible value reflecting that there has been no previous game round:

```
int lowestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

if (currentScore < lowestScore) {
    lowestScore = currentScore;
    System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore + "  NEW LOW SCORE!");
    System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);
    
} else {
    System.out.println("Score = " + currentScore);
    System.out.println("Lowest Score = " + lowestScore);
}
```